# Marionette CompositeView - Child remains in this.children

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, composite-view

I'm currently working with a `CompositeView`. The problem is, when I call `destroy()` on one of the child views from the `CollectionView` part, it still remains in the `this.children._view` obejct, even do it disappears from the screen.
If I try to do anything with it (let's say call `destroy()` again) than it says, it has already been destroyed, but than why doesn't it get deleted from the object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Child views are not parent aware

This may sound annoying, but it's set up like that by design, since a CollectionView child may also exists on its own. As far as I can't tell children of a Collection View are not aware that they are children (except for the case that the model is destroyed [and thus removed from permanent storage]).

## `CollectionView.removeChildView` can help

However, Marionette does expose a `CollectionView` method that is made exactly for what you want to do, `CollectionView.removeChildView(view)`.

`CollectionView.removeChildView` will remove the view from the DOM, destroy the view (remove any listeners on the view) and remove it from the `children` container. Just pass in one of your views.

If you need some tips on how to trigger `CollectionView.removeChildView` on an event on your child view, drop me a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much, thats exactly I was looking for.